# Cyclic Grants in SQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, authorization

I wonder what the result of the following grant/revokes is according to the SQL standard. Suppose `A` created a table `tab` and there are four users (i.e., `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`). The SQL commands are:

```
grant select on tab to B with grant option;   (by A)
grant select on tab to C with grant option;   (by B)
grant select on tab to B with grant option;   (by C)
grant select on tab to D with grant option;   (by A)
grant select on tab to C with grant option;   (by D)
revoke select on tab from B;                  (by A)
```

In Posgresql, it complains that it is not allowed to grant a privilege to grantor. In MySQL, it is allowed and the privilege of `B` is revoked although there is a path `system`->`A`->`D`->`C`->`B` in the authorization graph. Therefore, I wonder what the standard say about this situation. Does it define how these commands are handled?

Comment: *what the standard say about this situation.* Each DBMS implements its own politics.

Comment: You can read the chapter about SQL Authorization here: https://sql-99.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapters/15.html. This document summarizes the SQL-99 standard in less formal language. What the standard says about it is academic, and not necessarily applicable to any given implementation of SQL. Every SQL product (you tagged mysql and postgresql) has variation in how they choose to implement it, and they may not conform to the SQL standard perfectly.

Comment: @Akina Still, the standard is relevant.